# ASP.NET Web API CreatedAtRoute return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I'm trying to build a test web API controller, just for the purpose of understanding web API. I'm wrote the following web API controller:

```
[Route("api/books")]
public class BookController : Controller
{

    public IEnumerable<Book> Get()
    {
        List<Book> books = new List<Models.Book>();
        books.Add(new Book { Title = "Test Title 1", Author = "Test Author 1", ISBN = "Test ISBN 1" });
        books.Add(new Book { Title = "Test Title 2", Author = "Test Author 2", ISBN = "Test ISBN 2" });

        return books;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Book Get(int id)
    {
        return new Book { Title = "Test Title 1", Author= "Test Author 1", ISBN="Test ISBN 1", PublishingDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-90).AddDays(-73) };
    }


    //[HttpPost]
    //public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Book book)
    //{
    //    string str = "Post request received";

    //    return new JsonResult(str);
    //}


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Book book)
    {            
        //return CreatedAtRoute("abi/books", new { controller = "Book", id = 1  }, book);
        //return CreatedAtRoute("Get", new { controller = "Book", id = 1  }, book);
        //return CreatedAtRoute("Get", book);
        //return CreatedAtRoute("abi/books", book);
        return CreatedAtRoute("abi/books/1", book);
    }
}
```

The `Get` and `Get(id)` methods work fine. The commented port method also works fine. In the other post method, I'm trying to use the `CreatedAtRoute` method. When I call this action using the postman tool, it returns `500 internal server error`. I tried several alternatives for the method parameters (as you can see in the comment return statements) but non of them worked.

This is the detailed error that I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied
>   values.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext
>   context)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
>   context, ObjectResult result)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__32.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__31.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__29.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__23.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: This is most probably a typo as you have `abi/books/1` instead of `api/books/1`. So the error is accurate as there is no route that starts with `abi`

Comment: I believe there are better ways to state your suggestion. Anyway, I could not delete the question. There's an error when I try to delete stating that questions that have answers cannot be deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be a misspelling in your HTTP POST return statement (`abi` should be `api`). Fixing that should do it. Also, it might be better to specify a route name for your HTTP GET method (i.e., GetBook). And in your HTTP POST return statement, pass in the route name along with the route value and object. Also, you should wrap your book object in an `ObjectResult` before you return it in you HTTP GET method.

```
// GET /api/books/{id}
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetBook")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var book = new Book { 
        Title = "Test Title 1", 
        Author = "Test Author 1", 
        ISBN="Test ISBN 1", 
        PublishingDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-90).AddDays(-73) 
    };
    return new ObjectResult(book);
}

// POST api/books
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Book book)
{
    if (book == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // code to add book to database
    //_context.Books.Add(book);
    //_context.Books.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute(
        routeName: "GetBook",
        routeValues: new { id = 1 },
        value: book);
}
```

Comment: `return Ok(book);` method would work as well in the Get actions. Just like how `return BadRequest();` was used in the POST action.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. There was a typo in my code (abi should be api) but correcting this didn't fix the problem, it was giving the Get method a name that fixed the problem.